# What is this object that followed me up the street?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I saw my first UAV last night as it followed me up the street in Lancaster, PA. Does anyone know what type of unit this is or who would own one? I am guessing it was the police? I am curious.

[image: Mystery UAV]

Answer (score 11):

This is a [quadcopter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadcopter), so called because it uses four rotors to generate lift. They are now made cheaply in China and can be purchased in most technology-related online shops. They are remotely controlled, so it is safe to assume that the owner was close, but not in plain view. It might have been the police, but it could as well be a hobbyist, taking his new toy out for a spin.

Since most units are equipped with a cheap webcam and a wireless link, I would guess he/she was sitting in front of a computer or using his/her smartphone for controlling the device and watching the camera stream.

Comment: There is one available (not quite the same unit) at my local Walmart for $80 USD.

Comment: The pilot could have actually been breaking some rules, without realizing it, if you are located within 3 miles of LNS (Lancaster airport).

Comment: At the time I was further than 3 miles away from LNS.

Comment: @CGCampbell: I've recently seen similar _on_ an airport, apparently recording an air show. It was probably arranged with the organizers though.